# Динамический роутинг во Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

На сайте есть линк Logo button

```
<router-link to="/">
   <b-navbar-brand class="mr-5">
       <img src="@/assets/images/icons/logo-icon.svg" alt="">
   </b-navbar-brand>
 </router-link>
```

Как реализловать логику - если мы находимся на адресу ('/tickets') тогда линк в кнопке 'ticketbus', во всех других случаях линк в кнопке должен быть на "/"

Answer (score 1):

**Прежде всего хотелось бы преложить использовать `name` впредь при навигации, если ваши роуты изменятся, name'ы вероятнее всего нет. К тому же `name` чаще всего будет короче чем ваш путь и по нему проще точно проверить текущее отображение**

Прочитать подробнее можно [в документации](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/named-routes.html#%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B).

Что касается непосредственно вашего вопроса, можно создать computed `link`

```
link () {
    if (this.$route.path === "/tickets") {
        return "/ticketbus";
    } else {
        return "/";
    }
}
```

Теперь код вашего компонента будет выглядеть так:

```
<router-link :to="link">
    <b-navbar-brand class="mr-5">
        <img src="@/assets/images/icons/logo-icon.svg" alt="">
    </b-navbar-brand>
</router-link>
```